# How do I show results from an api in flask

Tags: python, api, psql, imdbpy

I'm creating a movie database and I'm pulling my data from import imdbpy.

I'm currently stuck on my post route that allows the user to enter in a title, I would like for my database to return title, actor and plot.

The system should show the first movie that is available and not null and then it will be automatically added to there page. However, once i put in the code below, it takes me to a blank screen with the following:

```
titanic-None -None
```

the searched movie was `Titanic`

Post route in `app.py` that I'm working on

```py
@app.route("/users/<username>/movies/new", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def movie_show(username):
    """Show  Movie Search Form and process it."""
    if 'username' not in session or username != session['username']:
        raise Unauthorized()
    
    form = MovieForm()
    
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        title = form.title.data
        movies = moviesDB.search_movie(str(title))
        movie = Movie(
            title= title,
            username=username,
            
            
        )
        
        for movie in movies:    
            title= movies.form.get('title')
            actors=movies.form.get('cast')
            plot= movies.form.get('plot')
            return(f' {title}-{actors} -{plot}' )

        db.session.add(movie)
        db.session.commit()
        
        return redirect(f"/users/{movie.username}")
    else:
        return render_template("movies/new.html", form=form)
```

Anyone that can help would be amazing, Im new at coding, I've been working on this for a week...

Comment: I think you should split the search and insertion of a new title in two different endpoints. I don't think `GET /something/new` should insert anything in a database.

Comment: Im able to save data to my database but its not pulling the data from the api imdbpy.

Comment: When you say two different end points, are you referring to two different routes, or the two different routes, same name but one is a GET and one is POST?

Comment: Off top of my head I'd expect `POST /users/<username>/movies` to create a new movie based on data in the payload; `GET /users/<username>/movies/<movie_id>` to return data about a specific movie and `GET /users/<username>/movies` to return a list of movies for that user.

Comment: Okay, I've tried to set up the new routes and I'm not getting any results, the movie name pops up but the the actor, plot etc doesn't. Here is my code

Comment: @app.route("/users/<username>/movies")
def list_movies(username):
    """Return all movies"""
    movies = [movie.serialize() for movie in Movie.query.all()]
    movies=movies
    username=username
    redirect(f"/users/{movies.username}")

Comment: `@app.route("/users/<username>/movies/new", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def movie_show(username):
    """Show  Movie Search Form and process it."""
    if 'username' not in session or username != session['username']:
        raise Unauthorized()
    
    form = MovieForm()
    
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        title = form.title.data
        movie_id=moviesDB.search_movie(str(title))
        movie= request.form['title']   
        m = Movie(
        title= title,
        username=username)
        movie=m`

Comment: ' db.session.add(m)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(f"/users/{m.username}")'
        else:
        return render_template("movies/new.html", form=form)`'

Comment: `def get_movie(username, movie_id):
    """Return data on a specific movie"""
    title= request.form['title']
    actor = request.form['actor']
    plot = request.form['plot']
    movie_id=moviesDB.search_movie(str(title))
    newdata= movie_id=movie_id, title=title, actor=actor, plot=plot,
    username=username
    return render_template(f"/users/{movie_id.username}", newdata=newdata)'

Comment: @app.route("/users/<username>/movies/<int:movie_id>")

Comment: how can i return a certain movie from imdbpy? They have a search request of moviedb.search_movie('title of the movie') I am having a hard time getting that movie title , actor, and plot to generate.